# How to migrate repository data from Alfresco 4 to 5?

Tags: alfresco

I'm working on migration from Alfresco 4 to 5 and applying any add-ons on Alfresco 4 for the purpose is not applicable. Database used for the both versions are different from each other. I have tried with ACP files and it is very time consuming. Is there a size limitation on ACP files? What other methods can be used?

Comment: Just drop in the new war files for Alfresco 5, and let Alfresco take care of upgrading things for you?

Comment: @Gagravarr Files from the existing repository needs to be moved to the new one.

Comment: Why do you have a new repository though? Alfresco will happily upgrade a 4.x one into a 5.x one by dropping the new wars in, so there's no need to go about setting up a separate new repo!

Comment: @Gagravarr that's the requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use Standard Upgrade Procedure

What is your main intention? "Just" doing an upgrade from 4 to 5?

In that case the robust, easy way would be to:

1. Install required modules having custom models in your target sytstem (or if you customized models in the extension path than you have to copy that config)
2. backup and restore the alfresco repo database to your new (5.x) system. If your target system uses a different db product (not just a different version) you need to manage the db migration using db specific migration tools. It is no alternative to use Alfresco export/import.
3. sync `alf_data/contentstore` to your new system (make sure the db dump
   is always older or you need to do an offline sync)

During startup Alfresco recognizes that the repo needs to be upgraded and does everything. Check the catalina.out for any output during migration.

If you need a subset from your previous system it is much easier to delete the content afterwards (don't forget to purge the trash and you should configure the cleaner job not to wait 14 days).

### Some words concerning ACP

It is a nice tooling to export single directories but unfortunately it is limited:

- no support accross Alfresco versions (exactly your case)
- no support for site metadata / no site export/import (maybe it is working after the changes in 4.x when putting site metadata in nodes but I suppose nobody tested this)
- must run in one transaction. So hard limits depend on your hardware / JVM configuration but I wouldn't recommend to export/import more than some thousand nodes at once.
- If you really need to use export/import a huge number of documents you should use the import/export in a separate java process which means your Alfresco needs to be shut down. s. https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Export_and_Import#Export_Tool

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply and it's really helpful. Just a quick question what would be the best way to maintain the same nodeRef in the upgraded version. When you use bulk-export/ bulk-import tool, is there any possibility of doing this?

Comment: The bulk import does not maintain noderefs. The standard upgrade process described here does however.

Answer (score 2):

ACP does have a file limit (I can't remember the actual number), but we've had problems with ones below that limit too. We've given up on this approach in favor of using Alfresco bulk import tool.

One big advantage this tool has, it can continue a failed import from the point of failure, no need to delete the partially imported batch and start all over again. It can also update files as needed, something ACP method can't (would fail with DuplicateChildNameNotAllowed).

Comment: What did you use as the export tool? I have tried bulkexport tool and it doesn't maintain the versions for a given file.

Comment: What version of the tool did you use? The one shipped with Alfresco is the old one, you should use the one found on GIT. I've never tested the versions part of it, but it does say it supports it.

https://github.com/pmonks/alfresco-bulk-import

You can also check out the SSMR project, it will give you a good start on the export part of the whole deal.

https://github.com/lcabaceira/supersizemyrepo

Comment: I used the export tool from https://github.com/gsdenys/alfresco-bulk-export on Alfresco 4.2 It copies the versions of a given node.However when I imported the files using streaming bulk import tool which comes with Alfresco 5.1 versions for the nodes were not shown. I had a look at the bulk import tool in github link you sent. They do not support versions.

Comment: Are you sure, the documentation says otherwise? In any case, if you end up using the bulk import tool, don't use the old Alfresco one, you're gaining nothing, and loosing much. https://github.com/pmonks/alfresco-bulk-import/wiki/Preparing-the-Source-Content